# Why can I get console.log(variable) to give my value but not return variable?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

In my code I'm loading data from json using d3.json - and in order to get it working I call another function once the data is loaded and pass the json across there for processing. This seems to be working, but still refuses to return anything but "undefined".

My code:

```
function GetDataFromJson() {
      var jsonData;
    d3.json("http://localhost:8000/pipeline.json", function(dataFromServer){
        jsonData = dataFromServer; 
          NewValue(jsonData);
     });
    }
```

and

```
function NewValue(data){
  var jsonData = data;
  headers = ["Won"];
  var myTotal = 0;
      chunks = (headers.map(function(priceRange) {
          return jsonData.map(function(d) {
            return {y: +d[priceRange]};
          });
      }));
      var myTarget = 10000000;
      chunks.forEach( function (arrayItem)
          {
            var l = 12;
            for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
              myTotal += arrayItem[i].y;
            };
          });
      myTotal = myTotal/myTarget*100;
      return myTotal;
}
```

I'm running this in Firefox Firebug using `GetDataFromJson()` and with the code above as-is I just get "undefined" in the console. If I add a line `console.log(myTotal)` before the return statement I get "undefined" and "37.5" returned as 2 separate lines - 37.5 being the correct value from the data I parsed in.

Why isn't return giving my myTotal as the result of the function whereas console.log() is?

**Adding Json data**

```
[
  {
    "Month": "Jan",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 1000000,
    "Lost": 350000
  },
  {
    "Month": "Feb",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 750000,
    "Lost": 2750775
  },
  {
    "Month": "Mar",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 250000,
    "Won": 2000000,
    "Lost": 750000
  },
  {
    "Month": "Apr",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 1375000,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "May",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 750000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Jun",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 325000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Jul",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 50000,
    "Demonstrating": 1000000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Aug",
    "Prospecting": 10000,
    "Qualifying": 35000,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Sep",
    "Prospecting": 12250,
    "Qualifying": 22500,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Oct",
    "Prospecting": 0,
    "Qualifying": 0,
    "Demonstrating": 0,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Nov",
    "Prospecting": 100000,
    "Qualifying": 325000,
    "Demonstrating": 750000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  },
  {
    "Month": "Dec",
    "Prospecting": 120000,
    "Qualifying": 370500,
    "Demonstrating": 670000,
    "Negotiating": 0,
    "Won": 0,
    "Lost": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: You can't do that.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: please give some sample json data

Comment: Thanks @SLaks - I read the blog, and it seems I need promises to get this to deliver the result myTotal from the NewValue function. I can't quite understand how I'd do that based on your article - can you help elaborate how I can use a promise in this instance please?

Answer (score 1):

`d3.json` is an asynchronous (non-blocking) function. That means it gets called, but the flow of your program keeps running. Therefore your `GetDataFromJson` returns before `d3.json` is actually finished and `d3.json` completes at a later time, once it has fetched the JSON data through the `HTTP` request.

Solution with callback functions:

```
// Pass a "callback" function that will get called once
// the asynchronous task of downloading JSON data is finished.
function GetDataFromJson(callback) {
    var jsonData;
    d3.json("http://localhost:8000/pipeline.json", function(dataFromServer){
        jsonData = dataFromServer; 
        callback(NewValue(jsonData));
    });

    // You don't have this return statement in your code, but it's implied.
    // This line gets called before d3.json is finished.
    // It's the line that gives you the undefined when you do 
    // console.log(GetDataFromJson(...));
    // To test this, try changing it to return "foo",
    // you will get "foo" instead of undefined.
    return;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
// The inline callback function we pass will get called
// once the async task is finished. Then we can handle the result.
GetDataFromJson(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Note: You can find ways to make that `HTTP` request synchronous (blocking) and make it work the way you anticipated, but it's not a good practice.

If you'd like to learn more how the event-loop works, I highly recommend this talk by Philip Roberts at JSConf EU 2014, named ["What the heck is the event loop anyway?"](http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html).

Comment: Thanks - when I do this I can get the console.log(result) to work - but if I change that to "return result;" I get "undefined" again - the NewValue function is working well but for some reason return won't play ball.

Comment: This is the same behaviour I get when just calling it the same way as my original post too - I thought invoking NewValue(jsonData) would ensure the code waits for jsonData to be loaded in this setup before calling NewValue - and if I console.log the elements in NewValue (e.g. "data", "chunks", myTotal" etc they are all populated with the correct data).

Comment: I edited the 1st code snippet in my answer to give you better insights why you can't do the normal return-and-grab-value flow, when async functions are involved. You basically have to carry out the result logic inside the body of the callback function. Note that `d3.json`'s second argument is a callback function as well, to address the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks @Quiriacus - I'd kind of stumbled into the realisation that my function would return "undefined" as well as the data I need. My problem is getting the data back out of your `GetDataFromJson(function(result){ console.log(result) ;});` statement - it logs the result (as does the current code if I call `console.log(myTotal);` in `NewValue(data)` - but `return result;` still gives me `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: As @SLaks said in a comment above, you can't do that. Unless you find a way to make `d3.json` a synchronous function.

Comment: So there's not a method to load json into a function and return a result? I thought the point of pulling the var Jsondata out was to wait until it loads before passing it to the NewValue function, where I could do what I wanted with it. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `GetDataFromJson()` is returning `undefined` because this is the expected behaviour in JavaScript: `undefined` is the “default” returned value if a function does not specify one returned value, and your function `GetDataFromJson()` doesn't have any `return`.

Provided that both functions work (i.e., no problem with asynchronous codes), in your `GetDataFromJson()` function you should change this:

```
NewValue(jsonData);
```

for this:

```
return NewValue(jsonData);
```

So the function could return the same value that you see using `console.log`.

Comment: Sadly that also returns "undefined" - even though it still triggers NewValue.

Comment: That's why I said "provided that both functions work", see Quiriacus answer above. But, even without the asynchronous problem, your function would return "undefined", because it had no `return`.